# Is there a better way of going back to Cordova/Phonegap app from webview?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, back

Currently I am using this to load an external webpage from inside a Cordova app:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

and this to get back from www.example.com to my Cordova applicaion:

```
window.history.back();
```

and it works. However, if I dig further down the www.example.com page, it requires a back button/link on every www.example.com subpage (for example: www.example.com/page1.html, www.example.com/page2.html, ...) to be able to get to the www.example.com page that I landed on in the first place. Once I am on that first page, I am able to click back one more time to get to the Cordova app.

Is there a better way of doing this using only javascript so I could go back to the Cordova app directly from any subpage on www.example.com? Thank you.

(I am currently working on this on iOS, but I would like it to be as portable as it gets so I am trying to avoid as much Objective-C and Java coding as I can)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using phonegap 2.1, then go to res/xml/config.xml
edit this line and change it from "false" to "true"

```
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
```

This will enable using browser history in the application.
So navigating back to a previous url is just via

window.history.go(-1)

Comment: In latest Cordova the setting is deprecated and removed. But defaults to true.